# Как установить модуль пакета Turtle?

Tags: python, turtle

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу установить модуль пакета Turtle?

Answer (score 2):

[Turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) - это встроенная библиотека. Вам достаточно для работы с ним импортировать её:

```py
import turtle
```

Comment: Может быть и стандартная, только вот она работает на базе tkinter, а tkinter может оказаться не установлен (например, сняли одну галочку при установке Python на Windows), и при импорте будет вылетать ошибка `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'`. Нужно уточнять подробности вопроса.

Comment: @insolor вполне возможно, что tkinter не установлен. Спасибо за замечание, в следующий раз буду уточнять.

Comment: @insolor Ага. На Убунте вообще ткинтера нет в встроенном питоне — надо `sudo apt install python3-tkinter` ;)